# Installation failed TeX Live 2021 on Windows 10 - Decompression error

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

I am trying to install TeX Live 2021 on my windows 10 computer (x64).

I have downloaded the install-tl.zip archive from https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

I unzipped it and then ran install-tl-windows.bat as administrator.

After running the standard installation, it fails because I have decompression errors on the packages whose name contains *.win32.*. Which is strange...

Here is an overview of the logs (for information "Le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable" = "The specified access path cannot be found."):

```
Installing to: C:/texlive/2021
Installing [0001/4309, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: texlive.infra [430k]
Installing [0002/4309, time/total: 00:02/04:46:52]: texlive.infra.win32 [2722k]
Le chemin d'accŠs sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
TLPDB::_install_data: Decompressing C:\Users\BRANTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\7ECRMTiNF7\19UUYWUHOy/texlive.infra.win32.tar.xz failed for https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/texlive.infra.win32.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install texlive.infra.win32
                           texlive.infra.win32 will be retried later.
Installing [0003/4309, time/total: 00:04/09:33:45]: tlperl.win32 [7010k]
Installing [0004/4309, time/total: 00:11/01:31:00]: 12many [376k]
Installing [0005/4309, time/total: 00:13/01:42:23]: 2up [56k]
Installing [0006/4309, time/total: 00:15/01:57:18]: a0poster [119k]
Installing [0007/4309, time/total: 00:16/02:03:16]: a2ping [69k]
Installing [0008/4309, time/total: 00:18/02:17:29]: a2ping.win32 [1k]
Le chemin d'accŠs sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
TLPDB::_install_data: Decompressing C:\Users\BRANTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\7ECRMTiNF7\f5w3tlwIak/a2ping.win32.tar.xz failed for https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/a2ping.win32.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install a2ping.win32
                           a2ping.win32 will be retried later.
Installing [0009/4309, time/total: 00:18/02:17:29]: a4wide [133k]
Installing [0010/4309, time/total: 00:20/02:30:18]: a5comb [91k]
Installing [0011/4309, time/total: 00:21/02:36:05]: aaai-named [6k]
Installing [0012/4309, time/total: 00:22/02:43:25]: aalok [187k]
Installing [0013/4309, time/total: 00:24/02:54:21]: aastex [1188k]
Installing [0014/4309, time/total: 00:26/02:45:39]: abbr [4k]
Installing [0015/4309, time/total: 00:27/02:51:58]: abc [288k]
Installing [0016/4309, time/total: 00:29/02:59:22]: abnt [121k]
Installing [0017/4309, time/total: 00:31/03:09:27]: abntex2 [4508k]
Installing [0018/4309, time/total: 00:35/02:27:45]: aboensis [34288k]
Installing [0019/4309, time/total: 00:54/01:08:00]: abraces [235k]
Installing [0020/4309, time/total: 00:56/01:10:11]: abstract [154k]
Installing [0021/4309, time/total: 00:58/01:12:28]: abstyles [151k]
Installing [0022/4309, time/total: 00:59/01:13:29]: academicons [131k]
Installing [0023/4309, time/total: 01:00/01:14:32]: accanthis [653k]
Installing [0024/4309, time/total: 01:02/01:16:01]: accents [237k]
Installing [0025/4309, time/total: 01:04/01:18:06]: accessibility [529k]
Installing [0026/4309, time/total: 01:06/01:19:42]: accfonts [37k]
Installing [0027/4309, time/total: 01:08/01:22:04]: accfonts.win32 [1k]
Le chemin d'accŠs sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
TLPDB::_install_data: Decompressing C:\Users\BRANTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\7ECRMTiNF7\IitTc5PIJ8/accfonts.win32.tar.xz failed for https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/accfonts.win32.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install accfonts.win32
                           accfonts.win32 will be retried later.
Installing [0028/4309, time/total: 01:08/01:22:04]: accsupp [331k]
Installing [0029/4309, time/total: 01:10/01:23:56]: achemso [890k]
Installing [0030/4309, time/total: 01:13/01:26:02]: acmart [3570k]
Installing [0031/4309, time/total: 01:17/01:24:57]: acmconf [111k]
Installing [0032/4309, time/total: 01:19/01:26:59]: acro [1254k]
Installing [0033/4309, time/total: 01:21/01:27:14]: acronym [296k]
Installing [0034/4309, time/total: 01:23/01:28:55]: acroterm [160k]
Installing [0035/4309, time/total: 01:25/01:30:49]: active-conf [327k]
Installing [0036/4309, time/total: 01:27/01:32:25]: actuarialangle [128k]
Installing [0037/4309, time/total: 01:30/01:35:24]: actuarialsymbol [295k]
Installing [0038/4309, time/total: 01:31/01:35:58]: addfont [52k]
Installing [0039/4309, time/total: 01:33/01:38:00]: addliga [19k]
Installing [0040/4309, time/total: 01:34/01:39:01]: addlines [139k]
Installing [0041/4309, time/total: 01:36/01:40:53]: adfathesis [151k]
Installing [0042/4309, time/total: 01:38/01:42:43]: adforn [391k]
Installing [0043/4309, time/total: 01:40/01:44:08]: adfsymbols [403k]
Installing [0044/4309, time/total: 01:42/01:45:30]: adhocfilelist [30k]
Installing [0045/4309, time/total: 01:43/01:46:29]: adigraph [478k]
Installing [0046/4309, time/total: 01:45/01:47:41]: adjmulticol [303k]
Installing [0047/4309, time/total: 01:47/01:49:11]: adjustbox [765k]
Installing [0048/4309, time/total: 01:48/01:48:49]: adobemapping [2120k]
Installing [0049/4309, time/total: 01:53/01:50:02]: adrconv [686k]
Installing [0050/4309, time/total: 01:54/01:49:49]: adtrees [356k]
Installing [0051/4309, time/total: 01:56/01:51:08]: advdate [146k]
Installing [0052/4309, time/total: 01:57/01:51:50]: ae [84k]
Installing [0053/4309, time/total: 01:58/01:52:39]: aeguill [29k]
Installing [0054/4309, time/total: 01:59/01:53:33]: aesupp [4394k]
Installing [0055/4309, time/total: 02:04/01:50:46]: afm2pl [50k]
Installing [0056/4309, time/total: 02:05/01:51:35]: afm2pl.win32 [15k]
Le chemin d'accŠs sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
TLPDB::_install_data: Decompressing C:\Users\BRANTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\7ECRMTiNF7\mrI4q1l9G8/afm2pl.win32.tar.xz failed for https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/afm2pl.win32.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install afm2pl.win32
                           afm2pl.win32 will be retried later.
Installing [0057/4309, time/total: 02:06/01:52:29]: afparticle [551k]
Installing [0058/4309, time/total: 02:07/01:52:29]: afthesis [45k]
Installing [0059/4309, time/total: 02:08/01:53:17]: aguplus [351k]
```

What can I do ?

Thanks for your help!

Matthieu

---

Edit:
Actually, the problem also appears for packages whose name does not contain "win32".

```
Installing [0768/4309, time/total: 32:22/02:54:23]: collectbox [276k]
Installing [0769/4309, time/total: 32:25/02:54:35]: collection-basic [1k]
Installing [0770/4309, time/total: 32:25/02:54:35]: collection-bibtexextra [2k]
Le chemin d'accŠs sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
TLPDB::_install_data: Decompressing C:\Users\BRANTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\7ECRMTiNF7\frRS1eno9T/collection-bibtexextra.tar.xz failed for https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/collection-bibtexextra.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install collection-bibtexextra
                           collection-bibtexextra will be retried later.
Installing [0771/4309, time/total: 32:26/02:54:41]: collection-binextra [1k]
Le chemin d'accŠs sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
TLPDB::_install_data: Decompressing C:\Users\BRANTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\7ECRMTiNF7\RIaj6rhYJ8/collection-binextra.tar.xz failed for https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/collection-binextra.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install collection-binextra
                           collection-binextra will be retried later.
Installing [0772/4309, time/total: 32:26/02:54:41]: collection-context [1k]
Le chemin d'accŠs sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
TLPDB::_install_data: Decompressing C:\Users\BRANTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\7ECRMTiNF7\G3uOJ0hWHe/collection-context.tar.xz failed for https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/collection-context.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install collection-context
                           collection-context will be retried later.
Installing [0773/4309, time/total: 32:27/02:54:46]: collection-fontsextra [2k]
Le chemin d'accŠs sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
```

Comment: Do you have some virus protection system which could block the binaries?

Comment: btw: I never install as admin, I simply run the batch file with my normal user account rights.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't have any other anti virus system than the one provided by default with windows.

Comment: ask on the texlive mailing list.

Comment: Just sending a mail to tex-live@tug.org ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to install Live Tex using the procedure described here:

https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html

Using Cygwin to create the local mirror.
Then unzipping the install-tl.zip archive and executing the install-tl-windows.bat file